# Passing Data From Views in Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

Hello everyone — I am a beginner in iPhone programming and Core Data. I am currently trying to learn some of the theory behind Core Data, and have been using [this](http://timroadley.com/2012/02/12/core-data-basics-part-2-core-data-views/) tutorial to help me implement it in my app.

The tutorial teaches by making the main view a `UITableViewController` that lists the saved objects and another `UITableViewController` that saves objects (where you enter in the attributes).

The app that I am creating has 3 views. The main view is a plain `UIViewController` (it handles calculations), you are able to save your calculations by tapping a `UIBarButtonItem` that brings you to the second view where you enter in more specific attributes. Once you tap save, you are taken BACK to the main view, where you are able to tap a Show Saved button to access the `UITableViewController` containing saved objects.

I have included #imported the `UITableViewController` files into my main view's interface file, but when I run the program, I get an error on this line in my `prepareForSegue` method:

```
    addShoeSizeTVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

The error is "Property managedObjectContext not found on object of type 'SSFViewController*'" I understand the meaning of this error — I don't have any object called managedObjectContext in my SSFViewController class, but I figured that if I included my file that DOES contain managedObjectContext that it would still be recognized. I should add, that in the tutorial, the `prepareForSegue` method was contained in the list view for the segue to the add new object `UITableViewController`. I moved this method to my `mainViewController`.

I also get an error in my App Delegate in my `ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

I understand that this stems from the same problem with the other error (it gives the same error message).

I do not understand how to pass data going from my viewA (mainView), to viewB (add object), back to viewA, then to viewC (view saved objects). I have heard about delegation and am using it in my `prepareForSegue` method in my `SSFViewController` main view:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Add Object Segue"]) {

        NSLog(@"Setting ObjectsTVC as a delegate of AddObjectTVC");
        AddObjectTVC *addObjectTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        addObjectTVC.delegate = addObjectTVC.self;
        addObjectTVC.managedObjectContext = addObjectTVC.self.managedObjectContext;
    }
}
```

Also on the `addObjectTVC.delegate = addObjectTVC.self;` line I get a warning that says "Passing 'AddObjectTVC*' to parameter of incompatible type 'id'"

Do I have to set up an `NSManagedContext` or another delegation method in my main view? Or is it something that I must add to any of my Table views???

Thank you very much. I feel like this is a simple problem to solve, if provided with the right information. I am happy to post any other methods that I used if needed to solve the problem. I am a beginner, so it would be great if you could explain in a beginner-friendly way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want data from ViewA to ViewB, insert a property in the ViewB and you can pass data from ViewA to this @property

**Example**

ViewB:

> @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *yourName;
>   (don't forget to call @synthesize yourName )

ViewA: (in prepareForSegue method)

> "ViewB-Controller" *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
>   controller.yourName = self.name

--> name will be passed to ViewB

Second:
I prefer a delegate which send from ViewB to ViewA "Hey please save your data". It keeps your controller easy and smart, and you don't have to manage the save method from all view controllers. Delegate is an important chapter in iOS and it can be very frustrated for a beginner. (I was in the same situation 9 months before ;))
Search for a delegate example and try to understand how it works (learning by doing), if you have further question about delegate, I will friendly respond to your question.

Comment: Is it possible to pass 2 things in the prepareForSegue? An 'managedObjectContext' and some 'data-name-ID-object'?

Comment: I would access to 'managedObjectContext' over a property and wouldn't pass it in the prepareForSegue method. It's easier to understand and much cleaner.
Why you don't use the sender object in the prepareForSegue method for identify the touched object?

Comment: Everybody says good code-design is to pass managedObjectContext along views, especially in prepareForSegue. But I solved my issue to pass an object :) [[segue destinationViewController] setObjInNextView: myObj ]; and declare the method in the next view

Comment: that's true, but you access to managed object context over a property and assign that to the view. You never pass the managed object context to the method directly.
It looks like this:
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
...
// implement managedObjectContext as a new property
yourNextView.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
}

Comment: Agree. I already have a property for it. So I think we are on the same path.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the view controller that has the [managedObjectContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003608) property, but your [UIManagedDocument](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIManagedDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010905).

The context is typically described as the 'scratch pad' in which your app will work with the data store.